# MySQL Where Name is Like Part of Array

Tags: mysql

I have a value "Berlin, Paris, London, ..." and I Want to do an MySQL Query

```
SELECT * FROM restaurants 
WHERE restaurant_city LIKE '%array%';
```

To get all restaurants where the city contains EITHER Berlin OR Paris OR London

How can I realize that?

Comment: where does the array come from and in which format?

Comment: SELECT * FROM restaurants WHERE restaurant_city IN ('Berlin','Paris','London');

Comment: @Strawberry earlier I also understood it but Moskau wants to pass array instead of cities.....

Comment: You have to implode the array and passed it to query using REGEXP. Look at the answer below

Comment: @SantoshJagtap: OP doesn't **have to**. There are several tricks for this. We can also get it done from sql itself.

Answer (score 2):

If in mysql we can do

```
SELECT * from restaurants where restaurant_city REGEXP 'Berlin|Paris|London';
```

Implode the given array using '|' and then use this generated string in query (In php).

```
$comma_separated = implode("|", $array);
```

Use the comma separated string in query

Comment: Santhosh I think he is not mentioned PHP.

Comment: @kuttyraj Yes he not mentioned PHP. I edited my answer.

Comment: **@kuttyraj**: This question is tagged `mysqli`, Can we use `mysqli` without `PHP` ?

Comment: @RavinderReddy From his question, we might know that he is expecting sql result. Not PHP result. And It is not harder to do with normal SQL script. ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Do a reverse trick.

```
SELECT * FROM restaurants WHERE 'array' LIKE concat('%',restaurant_city,'%')
```

So the query will be like:

```
SELECT * FROM Table1 WHERE 'Berlin, Paris, London' LIKE concat('%',restaurant_city,'%')
```

Sample in [**SQL Fiddle**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d0c92/5)

Answer (score 1):

**Easiest way:**

This is working fine.

```
 SELECT * FROM restaurants WHERE 
 restaurant_city LIKE '%Berlin%' OR 
 restaurant_city  LIKE '%Paris%' OR 
 restaurant_city  LIKE '%London%';
```

Or else, you could do same how Raging Bull mentioned.

**See local sample test.**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 SELECT * FROM restaurants WHERE ( restaurant_city LIKE '%Berlin%' OR  restaurant_city LIKE '%London%')
```

Worked on my case ...

Answer (score -2):

Try it-

```
SELECT * FROM restaurants 
WHERE find_in_set (restaurant_city,'Berlin,Paris,London');
```

Comment: I have edited my query as per understanding with problem, so please review your -ve voting.

Comment: who ever doing -ve voting should update his/her remarks....what is wrong here in this query.